# Differentiability of $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can someone please verify this (I admit the proof is very terse, but is the reasoning correct)?

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x = 0$. Is $f$ differentiable at $x=0$? Justify your answer.

Clearly, the limit $$\lim_{x \longrightarrow 0} \frac{x \sin \frac{1}{x}}{x}$$ is not defined. To see that, note that the function $$g(x) = \sin \frac{1}{x}$$ is not defined on $J \backslash \{0\}$, where $J$ is any open interval containing $0$.

To see this, note that that $g$ is undefined at $x = n \pi$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: $g$ is only undefined at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's wrong. You seem to mix up $\sin \frac 1x$ with $\frac 1{\sin x}$. $\sin \frac 1x$ is defined everywhere on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$. The point here is, that $g$ does not have a limit at $0$, since for example with $x_n = (n\pi)^{-1}$, we have $x_n \to 0$, but $g(x_n) = (-1)^n$ does not have a limit.

Answer (score 2):

To consider the derivative at zero, use first principles:

$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\sin(\frac{1}{h})}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\sin\frac{1}{h}$.

this limit is undefined, so indeed the function is not differentiable at zero.

Answer (score 0):

Two bad errors in you reasoning.

1. the function $g$ is defined at every $x\neq 0$.
2. anyway you have to check that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$ does not exist. The fact that $g$ is not defined in $x=0$ is not relevant.