# Derivative of piece-wise function given by $x\sin\frac1x$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the function:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if $x\ne0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $x=0$} \end{cases}$$

Question 1: Is $f(x)$ continuous at $x=0$?

Question 2: What is the derivative of $f(x)$ at $x=0$ and how do I calculate it?

Comment: What do you think about it ?

Comment: I think f(x) is continuous, since the limit for x->0 of f(x) equals 0 which also equals f(0)

Comment: You are right. Can you express the limit to compute the derivative ?

Comment: Using the definition of the limit at f(0) I came up with f'(0) is not defined, because Sin(1/h) is undefined if h goes to 0

Comment: Then you are done.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason Mathematica tells me f'(0)=0

Comment: @ImreVégh Whom do you trust more? Mathematica or pen and paper?

Comment: This is not what Alpha says.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: as regards me, I would trust SE Mathematics :)

Comment: If I enter this in wolframalpha, it actually says f'(0)=0 "differentiate piecewise[{{x*sin(1/x), x!=0},{0,x=0}}]"

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018595/solving-x-sin-frac-1x-via-limit-definition and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830172/differentiability-of-fx-x-sin-frac1x-for-x-neq-0-and-0-for-x and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560486/uniform-continuity-of-fx-x-sin-frac1x-for-x-neq-0-and-f0-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ad 1, $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ (and hence throuhout) for example because $|f(x)|\le |x|$ for all $x$, so that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0=f(0)$.

Ad 2, we wish  to calculate $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\sin\frac1h$, which does not exist (the expression oscillates between $-1$ and $1$, consider $h=\frac1{2k\pi\pm\pi/2}$ with $k\in\Bbb N$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin(\frac 1 x) \in [-1, 1]$ for any $x \neq 0$, we find that 
$$ 0 \leq \vert f(x) \vert \leq \vert x \vert \; , \; \text{for any } x \neq 0 \; .$$
With the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), it follows, that 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0 = f(0)\; ,$$
so $f$ is continuous at $0$.

To decide, if $f$ is differentiable at the point $0$, we can check, if the limit
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h \sin(\frac 1 h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \sin\left( \frac 1 h \right)$$
exists. Now, choose sequences $\{x_k\}$ and $\{ y_k \}$, such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = \lim_{k \to \infty} y_k = 0$, but
$$ \sin\left( \frac{1}{x_k} \right) = -1 \quad \text{and} \quad \sin\left( \frac{1}{y_k} \right) = 1 \; ,$$
for all $k \in \Bbb N$, which shows, that the limit above does not exist, so $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.